# Solution using multinomial theorem raised to a negative power

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

The number of ways of selecting exactly $ 4 $ fruits out of $ 4 $ apples, $ 5 $ mangoes, $ 6 $ oranges is...

A) $ 10 $

B) $ 15 $

C) $ 20 $

D) $ 25 $

I did the solution writing all the possible ways, I am getting $ 15 $, which is correct. However, there is a way to solve this with a multinomial expansion of the negative power. Please explain.

The solution is: We need to find the $x^4$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$. I want to understand this in a detailed manner. My question is, why $x^4$? Why $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$ and not $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)?$$

Comment: I don't know about multinomial and negative power, but I know how to solve it using a binomial coefficient. See [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: I think star and bars have the same application as multinomial.

Comment: Same reaction as @Arthur : never heard of that. Googling with this set of keywords  "multinomial at the negative power" doesn't bring anything valuable, not to speak of applications to your issue. Stick to "stars and bars" reasoning.

Comment: The solution is: We need to find the $x^4$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$. I want to understand this in a detailed manner.
My question is, why $x^4$? Why $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)^3$ and not $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)$?

Comment: @Arthur, edited as suggested. Thank you.

Comment: You would get the same answer either way since you are selecting a total of four pieces of fruit.  The $x^5$ and $x^6$ terms do not contribute to the coefficient of $x^4$.  The use of $(1 + x + x^2  +x^3  + x^4)^3$ is just for ease of calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion of 
$$
(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)
$$
is, technically, the correct expression. There are 5 mangoes and six oranges available, and this is reflected in $x^5$ and $x^6$ appearing.

However, the fact that there are $5$ and $6$ mangoes and oranges isn't really relevant, because we are only picking four fruits in total. So the problem would have the same answer if you just removed one mango and two oranges from the setup, and just had four of each fruit available.

We see this in the algebra too: the $x^5$ and $x^6$ terms in the above expression cannot *possibly* contribute to the final coefficient of the $x^4$ term. So they may be removed to simplify the expression.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. However, how do we reach the point that the coefficient will be $6c4$? I understand that it is '$chose$ $4$' because of $x^4$. But, why $6$?